# Device Support removed

Tags: android

I have an existing app available on playstore which runs on min sdk 18. I had made some changes and try to update my app and when I uploaded my apk everything goes fine but before the publish on review section , playstore gives me a warning as below.

> Device support removed
>
> **Warning**
>
> Deactivation of this APK will result in your app being available for
>   new installs on fewer types of devices.
>
> **Tip**
>
> If this is an unintended change, then retain this APK in the new
>   release or ensure that your new APKs support all currently supported
>   devices.

Comment: Please provide your gradle & menifest file code

Answer (score 1):

This message is a warning which says that your new apk will be available for a fewer number of devices.

The reason is, you made changes which probably affected AndroidManifest.xml. You could add new permissions, feature, screen support etc. So this message will be helpful when you added one of them by mistake and you would make apk available for fewer people (who would like to do that by mistake?).

Go through your code changes (comparing to the previous build) to check what exactly makes this limitation happened.

In most of the cases it's totally fine, because it's just natural that during the development process, you request more regarding system or device and as a result, it will run on a smaller number of devices.

You can ignore this warning and go ahead with publishing if you're aware what you're doing.